# Combinations of identical objects of different kinds

Tags: combinatorics

A lift has a computer facility of recording the number of people who leave at each floor. It runs from floor $1$ to floor $6$. If $8$ people,$3$ men and $5$ women, are inside the lift, how many different records are possible? If the computer can further distinguish a man from a women, how does the answer change?
If it is not possible to differentiate gender, i figured it is the same as the number of non-negative solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=8$, i.e $(8+5)!/8!5!$.
I am unable to answer the second part.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just break it up into two parts, for men and women,
proceed as you did before, separately for the two parts, and multiply.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. So it would be (8!/3!5!)*(10!/5!5!). Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you're welcome !